# kendo ui how to filter dataSource requestStart

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

## Main Problem

My current problem is the refresh progress when updating a grid datasource. I have change my code use the *kendo.ui.progress* in that way when requestStart event starts I ser the kendo.ui.progress to true. This activates the loading image when it end it calls the requestEnd.

The problem is that this event is hapenning for sorting and filtering. And I want it to only trigger for the read function of the dataSource. This problem makes the grid to use the progress endlessly.

Is there some way to filter in the **requestStart** and **requestEnd** only activate on the transport *read*?

### My DataSource Code

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: url_Obtener_Periodo,
      type: "POST"
    },
    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
      if (operation == "read" && options) {
        return {
          "periodo.Year": $("#periodo-anio").val(),
          "periodo.Month": $("#periodo-mes").val(),
          "Filtro": $("#Filtro").val()
        };
      }
    }
  },
  requestStart: function (e) {
    kendo.ui.progress($("#grid-container"), true);
  },
  requestEnd: function (e) {
    kendo.ui.progress($("#grid-container"), false);
  },
  schema:{
    model: {
      id: "Codigo_De_Pedido",
      fields: {
        Codigo_De_Pedido: { type: "number" },
        Fecha_Y_Hora_De_Creacion: { type: "date" },
        UserName: { type: "string" },
        Nombre_Del_Usuario: { type: "string" },
        Codigo_Del_Vendedor: { type: "number" },
        Nombre_Del_Vendedor: { type: "string" },
        Is_Pedido_Closed: { type: "bool" },
        Estado: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  },
  pageSize: 10
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _use the progress endlessly_?

Comment: If you only want to add it in `transport.read`, why do not invoke `kendo.ui.progress` inside `transport.read`? or since you are using `parameterMap` do it there conditional to `operation === "read"`.

Comment: With progress endlessly I mean that after reading. If you use the grid for *sorting* or *filtering* it fires on requestStart but never calls **requestEnd**.

Comment: Which version of Kendo UI are you using? Could you check that you have latests? It worked for me with 2013.1.319

Comment: The version I'm using is ´v2012.3.1114´. I have found a solution.

1. Removing the requestEnd. (Start the progress)
2. Add dataBound event for the Grid. (End the progress)

Answer (score 0):

The changes I did to solve the progress endlessly problem where 2.

- Removing requestEnd function from the dataSource
- Adding dataBound function to the Grid

## Data Source Code

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: url_Obtener_Periodo,
      type: "POST"
    },
    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
      if (operation == "read" && options) {
        return {
          "periodo.Year": $("#periodo-anio").val(),
          "periodo.Month": $("#periodo-mes").val(),
          "Filtro": $("#Filtro").val()
        };
      }
    }
  },
  schema:{
    model: {
      id: "Codigo_De_Pedido",
      fields: {
        Codigo_De_Pedido: { type: "number" },
        Fecha_Y_Hora_De_Creacion: { type: "date" },
        UserName: { type: "string" },
        Nombre_Del_Usuario: { type: "string" },
        Codigo_Del_Vendedor: { type: "number" },
        Nombre_Del_Vendedor: { type: "string" },
        Is_Pedido_Closed: { type: "bool" },
        Estado: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  },
  pageSize: 10,
  requestStart: function (e) {
    kendo.ui.progress($("#grid-container"), true);
  }
});
```

## Kendo Grid Code

```
kendoGrid = $("#selectable-pedidos").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  pageable: true,
  sortable: true,
  filterable: {
    extra: false,
    operators: {
      string: {
        startswith: "Comienza Con",
        eq: "Es Igual A",
        neq: "No Es Igual A"
      }
    }
  },
  dataBound: function (e) {
    kendo.ui.progress($("#grid-container"), false);
  },
  columns: [
    { field: "Fecha_Y_Hora_De_Creacion", title: "Fecha y Hora", template: "#= kendo.toString(Fecha_Y_Hora_De_Creacion, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') #" },
    { field: "Codigo_De_Pedido", title: "Código de Pedido" },
    { field: "Estado", filterable: true, title: "Estado" },
    { field: "Codigo_Del_Vendedor", title: "Código de Vendedor" },
    { field: "Nombre_Del_Vendedor", title: "Nombre de Vendedor" },
    {
      command: {
        text: "Ver Detalle de Pedido",
        click: function (e) {
          $("#empty").append("<form method='POST' action='/HojaDeRuta/GetById/'><input type='hidden' name='Codigo_Pedido' value='"
                            + this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")).Codigo_De_Pedido + "' /><input type='submit' /></form>");
          $("#empty input[type='submit']").click();
        }
      },
      title: " " 
    }
  ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things about your questions worth mentioning for those who read this:

> Is there some way to filter in the requestStart and requestEnd only
>   activate on the transport read?

Yes, but it will not help you.  The parameter of the event has a `type` property that will contain `read`, `update`, `destroy` or `create`.

```
 statementEntriesDS.bind("requestStart", function (e) {     
                switch (e.type) {
                    case "create":
                        alert('-> event, type "create".');
                        break;
                    case "read":
                        alert('-> event, type "read".');
                        break;
                    case "update":
                        alert('-> event, type "update".');
                        break;
                    case "destroy":
                        alert('-> event, type "destroy".');
                        break;
                }
            });
```

Your example code doesn't specify serverFiltering or serverSorting so sorting and filtering wouldn't cause an remote action.  You'll only get client-side sorting and filtering.  However, if they are specified they're all going to result in a `read` and that wouldn't really help you.

That you would not have the `requestEnd` event fire sounds odd.  You should probably add a handler for the `error` event and see if something is failing.

If you really want complete control over what's happening, you can specify a function for your `read`:

```
transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    kendo.ui.progress($gridContainer, true);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: carrierServiceBaseUrl + "/GetManualStatementsCarrierList",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (result) {
                            // notify the data source that the request succeeded
                            options.success(result);
                            kendo.ui.progress($gridContainer, false);                            },
                        error: function (result) {
                            options.error(result); // Call the DataSource's "error" method with the results
                            kendo.ui.progress($gridContainer, false);
                            notification.show({
                                title: "ERROR:",
                                message: result.statusText
                            }, "error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```